# Facebook LIKE Page iFrame Shows WebPage not available

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

I am trying to create a Like Button on my site for Facebook and I received the iFrame code from Facebook but it's not showing!

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FSuper-Short-Comedy-Show%2F105982759575529&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;action=like&amp;height=90&amp;appId=542903592396470" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:90px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It's working fine for me care to explain your problem or add relevant code and links.

Comment: Um I just got the code from Facebook and placed into my code via Abobe Dreamweaver CS3

Comment: It says were the iFrame should be `This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address: file://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FSuper-Short-Comedy-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=PASS_YOUR_FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID&amp;width=292&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=62\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:282px; height:62px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>
```

Instead of my 'PASS_YOUR_FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID', pass the pageid there.

For Eg of facebook developers page:

```
<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=19292868552&amp;width=292&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=62\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:282px; height:62px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>
```

Hope it helps. :)

**Final Edit**:

In your case for the specific page you are pulling at the moment, try this -

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=105982759575529&amp;width=292&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=62" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:282px; height:62px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Now try the edited version again, It should work like charm, There were backslashes in front of double quotes and they were doing the damage. Try the edited part (final Edit)

Comment: No worries, backslashes were doing the damage. :)

Comment: At least it got fixed and I greatly appreciate it!